# Doc2Vec and PySpark: Gensim Doc2vec over DeepDist

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, gensim, word2vec

I am looking at the `DeepDist` ([link](http://deepdist.com)) module and thinking to combine it with `Gensim`'s `Doc2Vec` API to train paragraph vectors on `PySpark`. The link actually provides with the following clean example for how to do it for `Gensim`'s `Word2Vec` model:

```py
from deepdist import DeepDist
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()
corpus = sc.textFile('enwiki').map(lambda s: s.split())

def gradient(model, sentences):  # executes on workers
    syn0, syn1 = model.syn0.copy(), model.syn1.copy()   # previous weights
    model.train(sentences)
    return {'syn0': model.syn0 - syn0, 'syn1': model.syn1 - syn1}

def descent(model, update):      # executes on master
    model.syn0 += update['syn0']
    model.syn1 += update['syn1']

with DeepDist(Word2Vec(corpus.collect()) as dd:
    dd.train(corpus, gradient, descent)
    print dd.model.most_similar(positive=['woman', 'king'], negative=['man'])
```

To my understanding, `DeepDist` is distributing the work of gradient descent into workers in batches, and the recombining them and updating at master. If I replace `Word2Vec` with `Doc2Vec`, there should be the document vectors that are being trained with the word vectors.

So I looked into the source code of `gensim.models.doc2vec` ([link](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/doc2vec.py)). There are the following fields in the `Doc2Vec` model instance:

1. `model.syn0`
2. `model.syn0_lockf`
3. `model.docvecs.doctag_syn0`
4. `model.docvecs.doctag_syn0_lockf`

Comparing with the source code of `gensim.models.word2vec` ([link](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/word2vec.py)), the following fields went missing in `Doc2Vec` model:

3. `model.syn1`
4. `model.syn1neg`

I think I do not touch the `lockf` vectors because they seem to be used after the training is done when new data points come in. Therefore my code should be something like

```py
from deepdist import DeepDist
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, LabeledSentence
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()

# assume my dataset is in format 10-char-id followed by doc content
# 1 line per doc
corpus = sc.textFile('data_set').map(
    lambda s: LabeledSentence(words=s[10:].split(),labels=s[:10])
)

def gradient(model, sentence):  # executes on workers
    syn0, doctag_syn0 = model.syn0.copy(), model.docvecs.doctag_syn0.copy()   # previous weights
    model.train(sentence)
    return {'syn0': model.syn0 - syn0, 'doctag_syn0': model.docvecs.doctag_syn0 - doctag_syn0}

def descent(model, update):      # executes on master
    model.syn0 += update['syn0']
    model.docvecs.doctag_syn0 += update['doctag_syn0']

with DeepDist(Doc2Vec(corpus.collect()) as dd:
    dd.train(corpus, gradient, descent)
    print dd.model.most_similar(positive=['woman', 'king'], negative=['man'])
```

Am I missing anything important here? For example:

1. Should I care about `model.syn1` at all? What do they mean after all?
2. Am I right that `model.*_lockf` is the locked matrices after training?
3. Is it ok that I use `lambda s: LabeledSentence(words=s[10:].split(),labels=s[:10]` to parse my dataset, assuming I have each document in one line, prefixed by a 0-padded 10-digit id?

Any suggestion/contribution are very appreciated. I will write up a blog post to summarize the result, mentioning contributors here, potentially to help others train Doc2Vec models on scaled distributed systems without spending much dev time trying to solve what I am solving now.

Thanks

---

Update 06/13/2018

My apologies as I did not get to implement this. But there are better options nowaday, and `DeepDist` haven't been maintained for awhile now. Please read comment below.

If you insist on trying out my idea at the moment, be reminded you are proceeding with your own risk. Also, if someone knows that `DeepDist` still works, please report back in comments. It would help other readers.

Comment: did you wrote that blog post? :) I'm really looking forward to your findings

Comment: Have you implemented this? I'd also be interested in training doc2vec in pyspark.

Comment: For people who are reading this: I did not get to implement this, until it's too late that I didn't think it would work. DeepDist uses Flask app in backend to interact with Spark web interface. Since it wasn't maintained anymore, Spark's update very likely broke it already. If you are looking for Doc2Vec training in Spark, just go for Deeplearning4J(https://deeplearning4j.org/doc2vec#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this question from remaining shown as open, here is how the asker resolved the situation:

> I did not get to implement this, until it's too late that I didn't think it would work. DeepDist uses Flask app in backend to interact with Spark web interface. Since it wasn't maintained anymore, Spark's update very likely broke it already. If you are looking for Doc2Vec training in Spark, just go for Deeplearning4J(deeplearning4j.org/doc2vec#)